# $\frac{X_N Y_N}{X_N Y_N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{a_k^2+ b_k^2}{2} = X_N Y_N \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{a_k^2}{2X_N^2}+ \frac{b_k^2}{2Y_N^2}$?

Tags: inequality

I'm reading Iosevich's: *A view from the top*. Here:

> [image]

I'm trying to pinpoint all the manipulations he did, I guess it is the following: Using $(1.1)$ several times, it gives:

$$a_1 b_1 \leq \frac{a_1^2 + b_1^2}{2}\quad , \quad \dots \quad  ,\quad a_n b_n \leq \frac{a_n^2 + b_n^2}{2}$$

Summing all the inequations, we have:

$$a_1b_1 + \dots + a_nb_n \leq \frac{a_1^2+b_1^2 + \dots + a_n^2 + b_n^2}{2}$$

Rearranging, we get:

$$a_1b_1 + \dots + a_nb_n \leq \frac{a_1^2 + \dots+ a_n^2  +b_1^2 + \dots  + b_n^2}{2}$$

Which gives us $X_N^2, Y_N^2$. Now it seems that he multiplies both sides by $\frac{X_N Y_N}{X_N Y_N}$ which is reasonable, my problem is (assuming that that is what he actually did) how:

$$\frac{X_N Y_N}{X_N Y_N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left[  \frac{a_k^2+ b_k^2}{2}\right] \stackrel{?}{=} X_N Y_N \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left[  \frac{\frac{a_k^2}{X_N^2}+ \frac{b_k^2}{Y_N^2}}{2}\right]$$

When I try to do the inverse of the distribution, I get:

$$X_N Y_N \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left[  \frac{a_k^2}{2X_N^2}+ \frac{b_k^2}{2Y_N^2}\right]= X_N Y_N \sum_{k=1}^{N}   \frac{a_k^2}{2X_N^2}+ X_N Y_N  \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \frac{b_k^2}{2Y_N^2}$$

Which gives me:

$$ \frac{X_N Y_N}{2X_N^2} \sum_{k=1}^{N}   a_k^2+ \frac{X_N Y_N}{2Y_N^2}  \sum_{k=1}^{N}  b_k^2= \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{\frac{ Y_N}{2X_N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}   a_k^2+ \frac{X_N }{2Y_N}  \sum_{k=1}^{N}  b_k^2}  $$

And it seems rather different than multiplying by $\frac{X_N Y_N}{X_N Y_N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of it this way: For each $a_ib_i$, the author writes $$a_ib_i = X_NY_N\cdot\left(\frac{a_i}{X_N}\cdot\frac{b_i}{Y_N}\right)\leq X_NY_N\cdot\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a_i}{X_N}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b_i}{Y_N}\right)^2\right]$$
and then sum over all $i$ to get $(1.2)$: $$\sum_{i=1}^N a_ib_i \leq X_NY_N\cdot\sum_{i=1}^N\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a_i}{X_N}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b_i}{Y_N}\right)^2\right]$$

Comment: Oh, I get it! We just use the inequality and the $a_i, b_i$ become $\frac{a_i}{X_N},\frac{b_i}{Y_N}$ by simple substitution and then we multiply both sides by $X_N Y_N$! Perfect.